# How we can restrict an IAM User to launch EC2 Instance and VPC via Cloudformation only?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

How we can restrict an IAM User to launch EC2 Instance and VPC via Cloudformation only. I don't want user to launch the EC2 instance and VPC directly by console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two options:

**Use a role with AWS CloudFormation**

When launching a CloudFormation stack, a role can be specified. This role can have the necessary permissions to launch the stack, even if the user doesn't have it.

See: [AWS CloudFormation Service Role - AWS CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-iam-servicerole.html)

**Use AWS Service Catalog**

AWS Service Catalog allows you to create a portfolio of offerings that users can launch. It uses a role to launch services even if the user themselves doesn't have permission to launch the services themselves.

See: [AWS Service Catalog Documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/documentation/servicecatalog/?id=docs_gateway)

Comment: **Use a role with AWS CloudFormation**

So do you mean I have to create a role with root account, that user can specify while launching the Stack?

Comment: Correct. The user will need `iam:PassRole` permissions for the role to be able to select it when launching the stack. The permissions would be best configured so they can only use the role with CloudFormation, or that specific stack so that they cannot separately assume the role and launch EC2 resources.